# Difference between element.value{} and .value{} where value is a class name in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm new to Web Design, and am learning HTML/CSS now. This question has been bugging me for several days:

If you have a CSS rule :

```
<p class="example">This is a sample paragraph</p>
```

Then, what are the differences between these selectors:

1. `.example {...}`
2. `p.example {...}`

Earlier, I used to think they refer the same thing. But on thinking more, I think there is this difference:

When we write the selector - `.example{...}`, the styles in this selector get applied to every element in the paragraph, be it text, image, `<a>`, `<b>`, `<em>` etc.

But if we write `p.example{...}`, even then all the styles get applied to every element in this selector.

The only difference which I could think of seems to be syntactic. `p.example{...}` refers to all `<p>` elements which have a class name of `example`. While, `.example{...}` picks up any element which has the class name of `example`.

Apologies if the question doesn't make sense, but I couldn't think of a better way of saying what I mean.

I also have an example here, just in case:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gaps between cells</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    table {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    td {
        background-color: #08d;
        padding: 15px;
        border: 2px solid #000;
    }

    table.one {
        border-spacing: 5px 15px;
    }

    table.two {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <table class="one">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="two">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this example, replacing `table.one{...}` and `table.two{...}` with just `.one{...}` and `.two{...}` doesn't seem to make any difference. Why?

Comment: You have answered yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.classname` takes all elements with this class.

```
<style>
    .classname {color: red;}
</style>

<p class=classname>This will be red</p>
<span class=classname>This will be red</span>
<p>This will be black</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cgsj4znn/

`p.classname` takes just paragraphs with this class.

```
<style>
    p.classname {color: red;}
</style>

<p class=classname>This will be red</p>
<span class=classname>This will be black</span>
<p>This will be black</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cgsj4znn/1/

Answer (score 1):

It's just not that, it's more than what you think. What you understood is correct, so when you use `.example` than it will apply styles to ALL the elements having a class of `.element`

When you use a selector like `p.element` it will target ALL the `p` tags having a `class` of `.element`

But it's not just this, now this is something where specificity comes in. So when you write `p.example` is considered more specific than just using `.example` so you should be following a general practice of declaring your selectors as least specific as they can be. For more information you should understand a concept in CSS called CSS Specificity.

[Here's a decent article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) for you which explains you CSS Specificity in a detailed manner.

---

As you said you are just getting into CSS, get a thumb rule that before you head off with declaring classes and ids, you should declare some general rule set for these tags specifically so that you don't have to mention for each and every element.

For example you can declare `font-family`, `font-size`, `color` and so on in the `body` tag declaration of your CSS so that it gets inherited by most of the tags. This will prevent you from re declaring the same thing for each and every element.

Comment: The article is very helpful, thanks. Just to confirm, when you mean least specific rules are better, `.example{}` is better than `p.example{}` right?

Comment: @Manish Yes, if you write `p.example{color: white;}` and later you have a selector which says `.example{color: red;}` so no matter in what ordered you have declared them in your stylesheet but your paragraphs will always be white in text until you override that with the same selector declared after the white one or you need to write even more specific selector.

Answer (score 0):

this is not really a question as you speculate with yourself. And yes you speculate correctly.

This is css 101 btw, if you have problems understanding (or dont understand) this you might want to consider going for online course such as

http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web

Answer (score 0):

As [Bhojendra Nepal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2138752/bhojendra-nepal) pointed out -> You have answered yourself.

> The only difference which I could think of seems to be syntactic.
>   `p.example{...}` refers to all `<p>` elements which have a class name
>   of example. While, `.example{...}` picks up any element which has the
>   class name of example.

To answer your question about your example:

You have a `table.one` in your css and a `<table class="one">` in your html.
Sure, if you remove the `table` from your css it won't make any difference 'cause you then say "Hey, apply to all objects with class one" (so it'll target your table again).
But if you change the `table` in your css instead of removing it (e.g. change it to `form.one`) then the css won't apply to your table anymore 'cause you say "Hey, just apply to forms with the class one"